# How would I display my partial based on the variable in the index function in my controller?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

How would I correctly display my partial based on the variable inside my index function?  I've tried many different ways in terms of using the variable in the if statement but to no avail, namely -  `{{ $test }}`, `"test"`, `$test`.  How can I make this work?

Here's the index function in my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
   $type = "abc"; 
   return view('view', compact("type"));
}
```

Here's my blade file:

```
@if($type === "abc")
 @include('myPartial') 
@endif
```

Comment: What you have listed here should be working, have you tried {{ dd($type) }} just to make sure it's actually getting defined? Are you getting an error message or is it just not including the view?

Comment: I ran `dd($type);` inside my index function, it's indeed being defined which's why this is so strange.

Comment: I mean did you put that in the view, so you can see if it's actually being passed correctly by compact

Comment: @AlecJoy oh, yeah I did.  It's showing abc correctly

Comment: Try with `@includeWhen('abc' === $type, 'view.name')`

Answer (score -1):

When you sent data to view using `compact()` you sent an array to view.

in your code you are sending this:

```
$type = ['type' => "abc" ]
```

if you want to use it in view you should use it as an array and like this:

```
{{ $type['type'] }} //output : abc
```

Comment: that doesn't work.  however, `{{ $type }}` does work.  I just want to check this value inside the if statement in blade browser and tried a lot of ways but to no avail.